# unable to run an automated test on agent machine using test manager

Tags: microsoft-test-manager

Following error is displayed on running an automated test on an agent machine via Test Manager. The test run is successful on local machine for the same build and same test.

**System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'WebDriver, Version=2.35.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.To**

Please help..!!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be helpful to provide more information about your test.

Comment: So, WebDriver looks like a Selenium testing framework? If that is the case then it needs to be on the test machine.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys,i got problem resolved myself by making changes to assemblyinfo.cs file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved, comment out the line following line in **AssemblyInfo.cs** file.

**[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]**

Comment: This worked for me. We had Selenium.WebDriver version 3.4.0 installed from Nuget.