# Could you help me with this error I got error in webdriver with TFS2015?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, configuration, tfs-2015

I try to run selenium webdriver with `TFS2015` in the last step I got a error run my tests"

> > System.IO.FileNotFoundException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'WebDriver, Version=2.53.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
> >
> > The system cannot find the file specified.WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.To enable assembly bind failure logging"

Answer (score 0):

WebDriver looks like a Selenium testing framework, based on the error message, maybe you could check whether you use/download the wrong version.

Below are similar issues for your reference:

[Could not load file or assembly 'WebDriver, Version=2.35.0.0 ...'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521891/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-webdriver-version-2-35-0-0)

[unable to run an automated test on agent machine using test manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162951/unable-to-run-an-automated-test-on-agent-machine-using-test-manager)